# augeas set value with whitespace failed

Tags: whitespace, vagrant, puppet, augeas

I've problem with augeas when I set value (augeas-0.10.0 is used with puppet-2.7.11) with whitespace, ex.

```
...

changes => "set *[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization'",
...
```

After saving I've got this error msg:

```
/augeas/files/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf/error = "put_failed"
/augeas/files/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf/error/path = "/files/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf/IfModule/directive"
/augeas/files/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf/error/lens = "/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/httpd.aug:76.18-77.49:"
/augeas/files/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf/error/message = "Failed to match \n    ({ /arg/ = /([^\001-\004\t\n \"']|\\\\\"|\\\\')+|\"([^\001-\004\n\"\\]|\\\\[^\001-\004\n])\"|'([^\001-\004\n'\\]|\\\\[^\001-\004\n])'/ }({ /arg/ = /([^\001-\004\t\n \"']|\\\\\"|\\\\')+|\"([^\001-\004\n\"\\]|\\\\[^\001-\004\n])\"|'([^\001-\004\n'\\]|\\\\[^\001-\004\n])'/ })*)?\n  with tree\n    { \"arg\" = \"/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization\" }"
```

I tried diffrent ways to escape this value, but every attempt failed with the same error.
What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks for any helpfull answers !

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

- your changes potentially create an `arg` node without a parent `directive` node, which is not valid with the `Httpd.lns` lens;
- you need to force quotes around the value because it contains spaces.

So (using `augtool`):

```
# Make sure the directive exists
set directive[. = 'FastCgiExternalServer'] FastCgiExternalServer
# Set the argument
set directive[. = 'FastCgiExternalServer']/arg '"/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization"'
```

should work better.

Comment: Yes, but this value /usr/lib/cgi-bin..., will be in double qoutes in fastcgi.conf, which is not correct format, apache after reload will fail. I had hope, that is any way to insert it without qoutes without any hacks...

Comment: If you must not have any quotes, then each of the parts should be a separate `arg` node. If you think this is wrong, you can file a bug against the Httpd.lns lens.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a bug. You mean httpd.aug file in lens directory in yours repository ?

Comment: The `Httpd.lns` lens is described in the `httpd.aug` file (which contains the `Httpd` module). You can report directly against the `Httpd.lns` lens, describing your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The "arg" is actually a list. Each argument should be enumerated:

```
defvar conf /files/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo
clear $conf/VirtualHost
set $conf/VirtualHost/arg "172.16.0.1:80"
set $conf/VirtualHost/directive "FastCgiExternalServer"
set $conf/VirtualHost/*[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg[0] "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
set $conf/VirtualHost/*[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg[1] "-socket"
set $conf/VirtualHost/*[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg[2] "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"
set $conf/VirtualHost/*[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg[3] "-pass-header"
set $conf/VirtualHost/*[self::directive='FastCgiExternalServer']/arg[4] "Authorization"
```

It produces the following file:

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.0.1:80>
FastCgiExternalServer -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</VirtualHost>
```